# What the parameter(?or prefix) in parentheses before class method's name do when i call it?

Tags: java, android

I am  new in Java(yes, and in English too=)).
What the prefix in parentheses before class method's name do?
For example,

```
(EditText)findViewById(R.id.text);
```

`R.id.text` is parameter, but what is the `(EditText)`prefix? What it do?

Comment: It's called casting.  Take a look here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

Answer (score 4):

That's how you `cast` objects in Java. Typically, you would do that if a method declares to return a general type, and you want to use the return object as a more specialized type (and you know that it actually is an instance of this specialized type). For instance, if you have a method that returns `Object`, but you know that the object is in fact a `String`, and want to use it as a `String`, you do:

```
String s = (String)myObj.doSomethingThatReturnsObject();
```

which if you didn't do the cast would have to be

```
Object o = myObj.doSomethingThatReturnsObject();
```

Answer (score 1):

It cast the result of the method to the EditText class.
That means you'll be able to use it as an object of that class, but it will fail if the object returned is not an instance of EditText or it's derived types.

So the method could be returning a interface reference, and you can cast it to an implementing class of that interface in order to use the behavior that it's not available on the interface.

Answer (score 0):

(EditText) prefix tries to cast the retrun Object in EditText type